# Insert value is not getting to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using `ASP.NET 4.0`, `C`#, `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

I receive the error

```
"Cannot insert the value NULL into the column 'columnID', table 'table name'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.  The statement has been terminated."
```

I have a query that gets the last ID value and places that into a `textbox`, then I take the `textbox.text` value to insert the ID into the table, see code below.

```
    string ID_Sel = "SELECT TOP 1 columnID FROM table ORDER BY columnID DESC";
    string ID_Ins = "INSERT INTO table (columnID) VALUES (@id)";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection string);
    SqlCommand cmdsel = new SqlCommand(ID_Sel, con);
    SqlCommand cmdins = new SqlCommand(ID_Ins, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader read = cmdsel.ExecuteReader();
    read.Read();
    string a = read["columnID"].ToString();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        string val1 = a.Substring(1, a.Length - 1);
        int b = Convert.ToInt32(val1) + 1;
        string val2 = a.Substring(0, a.Length - 6);
        a = val2 + b.ToSting("000000");
    }
    TextBox.Text = a;
    con.Close();
    TextBox.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmdins.Parameter.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox.Text);
        cmdins.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        error.Text = ex.Message;
    }
```

My `Textbox` displays the next ID for the record, but my error `textbox` displays:

```
"Cannot insert the value NULL into the column 'columnID', table 'table name'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.  The statement has been terminated."
```

My question is why does my `textbox` display the correct ID for the next record but I sending null to the database?

Comment: Your code as posted doesn't compile (you have `ToString` instead of `ToString()` and have a variable called `TextBox`).  Please post your _exact_ code so the true problem can be determined.  Or run it in the debugger and look for the problem yourself.

Comment: @DStanley I just finished verifying my code.  I did have a couple of corrections to make.  My for statement is needs to rmove the alpha from the ID, incrament and reapply the alpha.  that is working good.  Everything is running good, just my insert statement is giving me an error on the SQL side.

Comment: Did you look at the variables?  What is the value of `b`? Does it still throw an exception?

Comment: @DStanley b give just the numaric part of the ID as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Is the ID column an int? If so, perhaps try:

```
cmdins.Parameter.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
cmdins.Parameter["@id"].Value = Int.Parse(TextBox.Text);
```

Comment: the ID is an alpha numaric

Comment: I tried this for a Char datatype.  in the table it is Char.  I still received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as posted doesn't compile, however here's a *simplified* version that should be close:

```
string ID_Sel = "SELECT TOP 1 columnID FROM table ORDER BY columnID";
string ID_Ins = "INSERT INTO table (columnID) VALUES (@id)";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection string);
SqlCommand cmdsel = new SqlCommand(ID_Sel, con);
SqlCommand cmdins = new SqlCommand(ID_Ins, con);
con.Open();
var a = cmdsel.ExecuteScalar();  // use ExecuteScalar to get the only value
int b = Convert.ToInt32(a) + 1;
textBox.Text = b;
con.Close();
textBox.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
try
{
    con.Open();
    cmdins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", b);   //  use the variable instead of the TextBox property.
    cmdins.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
error.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: Well, since `b` is an `int` it can't be null, so something else is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the table name "table"